# Add audio rows after video rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make sure that audio rows gets added after the video rows with the code below. Note that I want it all in the same table. I assume I shouldn't use `prepend()` the way I do.

The expected result should look like this if you add 3 video rows and 2 audio rows, no matter what order you add them in:

```
video 3
video 2
video 1
audio 2
audio 1
```

```js
var videoCount = 1;
var audioCount = 1;
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
  var type = $('input[name="type"]:checked').val();
  if( type == 'video' )
  {
    var count = videoCount; videoCount++;
  }
  else
  {
    var count = audioCount; audioCount++;
  }
  $('table').prepend('<tr><td>' + type + ' ' + count + '</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="type" value="video" checked="checked" /> Video</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="type" value="audio" /> Audio</label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="New Row" />
<table></table>
```

Comment: Whats happening if you try adding "prepend" in "if" condition and "append" in "else" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am satisfied with the ans by Murali Nepalli but you don't need to go for different if else condition for video and audio when its already there once. I suggest keeping the code optimal. You can verify it on : [JSFiddle Verification](https://jsfiddle.net/xmv0o32f/1/)

So you can simply go for :

```
var videoCount = 1;
      var audioCount = 1;
      $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
        var type = $('input[name="type"]:checked').val();
        if( type == 'video' )
        {
          var count = videoCount; videoCount++;
           $('table').prepend('<tr><td>' + type + ' ' + count + '</td></tr>');
        }
        else
        {
          var count = audioCount; audioCount++;
          if( $('tr:contains("audio")').length > 0){
              $('<tr><td>' + type + ' ' + count + '</td></tr>').insertBefore($('tr:contains("audio")')[0]);     
           }else{
              $('table').append('<tr><td>' + type + ' ' + count + '</td></tr>');
           }
        }
      });
```

And it works like a pro.

Comment: I kept most of his code as it is for readability. Not becuse I could not think of merging those two if else blocks :)

Comment: Yes thats absolutely fine but all we need to implement is the best coding standards and optimal code, sans thinking of keeping the code intact and exact same. Ofcourse the site has been developed for bringing changes in the code to make it working, hasn't it ? So regardless of thinking for readability, one should prioritize optimality :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I verified this at https://jsfiddle.net/9cpk51eq/

```
  var videoCount = 1;
  var audioCount = 1;
  $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
    var type = $('input[name="type"]:checked').val();
    if( type == 'video' )
    {
      var count = videoCount; videoCount++;
    }
    else
    {
      var count = audioCount; audioCount++;
    }


    if(type=="video"){
       $('table').prepend('<tr><td>' + type + ' ' + count + '</td></tr>');
    }else{ 
       if( $('tr:contains("audio")').length > 0){
          $('<tr><td>' + type + ' ' + count + '</td></tr>').insertBefore($('tr:contains("audio")')[0]);     
       }else{
          $('table').append('<tr><td>' + type + ' ' + count + '</td></tr>');
       }     
    }

  });
```